# Amending PATH so that /usr/local/bin is ahead of /usr/bin

Tags: terminal, install, homebrew, command-line, path

I'm trying to install brew but get the following warning:

```
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

2to3
2to3-2.7
idle
idle2.7
pydoc
pydoc2.7
python
python-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
pythonw
pythonw2.7
smtpd.py
smtpd2.7.py

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
is ahead of /usr/bin in your PATH.
```

I have no idea how to amend the path.  I've explored several files from this stack overflow post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886114/using-brew-with-ruby-1-9-2), but can't find a relevan path to edit.  The only file that I do have that exists is my /etc/profile file which currently looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
    PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/local/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I wanted to just uninstall python then reinstall it through homebrew, but am a little nervous about breaking too many things at once.

Is there an easy way to amend the path?  Should I create a .bash_profile file?  Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, create a `.bash_profile` file in your home directory containing

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

and then do one of the following to make the change active

- execute `. ~/.bash_profile`
- execute `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in the current shell
- restart Terminal

Comment: @threenovation if the answer above is correct, can I suggest you mark it as answer (click the tick next to the answer)

Comment: I wonder if this should be exported? Child processes should have this new path also. Also: When I set up brew, it did not alert me that /usr/bin came before /usr/local/bin.

Comment: @StevenLu, it's already exported by the time you get to .bash_profile. It wouldn't hurt to explicitly export it again, but not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked  "Your system is raring to brew."

Comment: I seem to be getting duplicate entries in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to amend /etc/paths so that /usr/local/bin is listed before */usr/bin*.
You'll need to sudo your editor in order to do that.

One of the ways to open editor is

```
 sudo open -t /etc/paths
```

Comment: My PATH was configured correctly in my .bash_profile, but not in ``/etc/paths``. This worked beautifully.

Comment: Do NOT use this method for setting your path -- there is risk that non-terminal applications will pick up the "brewed" components and fail.  Using "sudo" should also be a red flag unless you truly understand what you're doing (especially with a user-level development system like Mac Homebrew).

Editing your .bash_profile and restarting terminal should be sufficient.

Comment: @rholmes So changes to `.bash_profile` affects interactive user shells only and not other applications?

Comment: @flow2k .bash_profile will affect interactive user shells. Any exported variables will be seen by applications launched from the shell command line (for example, launching a "regular" Mac app, or a command line command).  Some more details can be found here, but they're making a finer distinction than what you asked: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/  The answer by glenn jackman is the one to use.

Comment: @rholmes Got it - thanks. My point was that your comment from 2014 is about applications *not* launched from the shell. For these applications, `.bash_profile` will have no effect, but `/etc/paths` *will*. That was the point you were making in the 2014 comment, right?

Comment: @flow2k yes, you’ve stated that correctly.