# Softlink /bin/bash to a brew-installed bash

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, command-line, symlink

It is a question related to [this other one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24633/77314), but I can't comment.

I've updated to use bash 4 from brew installation. But I don't know if changing all the header scripts from:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

To

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Isn't a portable solution.

Moreover, some scripts check if the shell is a `/bin/bash` shell ([docker-toolbox in example](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/v1.8.2a/osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh#L60))

Before writing, I was recommended to read this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119179/77314
But the path solution is neither portable nor can apply on `docker` case (no direct source).

So I still doubt: is really a bad idea to softlink the `bash`?

Obviously, [targeting independent-version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24632/is-it-safe-to-upgrade-bash-via-homebrew#comment173435_24633).

Comment: Upgrading the OS could overwrite it - why update bash for these scripts - I can understand for terminal sessions - what improvement do you get -the scripts are probably written for older bash anyway

Comment: Upgrading: ok, it is true, so maybe someday I'll find myself in bash 3 without knowing ^^' ---- Scripts: when I write scripts, as I write code, I try to use latest software available, but most portable possible too. If I share my script with others and the bash line is not the `/bin/bash`, will complain anything?

Comment: It depends of the other person has an interpreter at the path you give - if not then it will not run - if they do hope it is the correct version - note if I have to write a shell script I will write it as sh as that will be portable, if more complex I'll use python, perl etc

Comment: Really nice comments! You have convinced me. Could you put them as answer?

Comment: With SIP (the "rootless" feature of 10.11), the problem kind of solves itself as you are no longer able to modify `/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

`#!/usr/bin/env bash` is the 'most portable' approach but `#!/bin/bash` is the standard convention on OS X and Linux. There are advantages to shebang with a stable system interpreter, and it's probably not worth using a newer Bash.

Comment: Is bash 4 less stable than 3? It is still updated version 3?

Comment: By stable I mean it's not likely to flip through versions, will survive OS upgrades and changes. You can still use Bash 4 as a shell but if your script doesn't use Bash 4 features I'd just stick with /bin/bash.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own bash symbolic link. Then use that in your script. You can then change the symlink to point to whatever you want. That's the approach used with java-alternatives and other platforms (ruby, python, etc.). Thus, they change the symlinks, and you have a new version in your environment.

Comment: Yes, I know **how**, my question was about _good_ or _bad_ idea in the bash case. Thanks anyway.