# to run latest emacs in terminal by typing "emacs"

Tags: terminal, homebrew, emacs

Question:

Because I use emacs-live, I used homebrew to install emacs-24.3. Now everytime I want to launch emacs of version 24.3 in terminal, I have to type "emacs-24.3" --- if I just type "emacs", it launches the original updated emacs came with Mac OS.

how can I configure these so that I only need to type "emacs" and launch the one installed by homebrew?

I use emacs in terminal, so the workaround that installing GUI version of emacs is not the solution what I am looking for. I use OSX Lion.

Note:

Solved the issue by [reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15492489/2430571)! the point was to restart my terminal after doing what you guys suggested...

For future visitors I will just post full procedure for solving this issue.

Solution:

1. Add following line in .bash_profile: `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49399/57744) post explained.
2. Close the terminal and restart again. If you don't restart, you will be stuck as I did :-)

Comment: You need to alter your PATH to put /usr/local/bin on the front - which is a duplicate

Comment: @Mark I did put /usr/local/bin on top of the rests, but it doesn't fix the problem -- typing emacs won't invoke the one installed by brew. Also followed instruction in your link but doesn't fix the problem as well...

Comment: → Seven: please insert the output of `echo ${PATH}` so as to understand why this question already dealt with (  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49389/amending-path-so-that-usr-local-bin-is-ahead-of-usr-bin ) doesn't help you correctly.

Comment: @Mark Just figured out I didn't restart my terminal! If you can post what you suggested in comment, I want to accept your post as answer :-)

Comment: @danielAzuelos Thanks Daniel, I just realized that I didn't restart my terminal looool!!

Comment: → Seven: you don't have to. Every modification of `.bash_profile` must be followed by:
another window opened (to check your shell is  still working) and `. ~/.bash_profile` to load it in your actual shell.

Comment: @danielAzuelos replace the and in the last sentence with an or

Comment: → Mark: this is an `and` because, the 1st trick is to ensure that the `~/.bash_profile` is error proof, the 2nd trick is to use it now that one knows it is OK. Perhaps should I put it in bold ;). In fact it isn't an `and` but an `&&`.