# Add a path to the system PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

Please help me figure out how to set a system wide PATH.....

I have upgraded svn to version 1.8.10 on osx 10.9

One of the required steps was adding the address of the current svn to the PATH.

```
export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH
```

Doing it in he current terminal, it allowed me to see the svn --version as 1.8.10, but upon closing the terminal, the version reverted to 1.7

I read that I can add this line to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

These files do not exist on my mac

I created the .profile and added the line above. From terminal, now I can get the correct version. But I am required to read this version from a different program (my Qt project calls a command

```
system(svnversion -n)
```

Even though in terminal I can get the correct svn version, the command above still gives an error "`This client is too old to work with the working copy...`"

The directions i find online, like [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/), say I also have to modify the .bash_profile (which does not exist on my machine) or edit/add something inside the `/etc/paths.d` directory - mine is empty !

Please help - how do I add this path to the system PATH variable ? Considering that all the default places to add it are missing ? And make it work from other programs not just Terminal ?

Comment: Feel free to edit this if you don't find an answer in the linked questions. Just make the question clearly different than the linked ones and we can reopen this.

Comment: For other apps like Finder - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87282/in-mountain-lion-how-do-i-set-in-one-place-the-path-environment-variable-for-a/87283#87283

Comment: And http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks/106814#106814

Comment: Or use homebrew or the file listed here... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49389/amending-path-so-that-usr-local-bin-is-ahead-of-usr-bin

Comment: After adding the desired path to the PATH through a couple of methods [run 'set' and the svn path is shown first in the PATH variable] - Qt Creator still uses the /usr/bin location. Found out that the svn path is written into Preferences... So while any of the above methods are great, it seems that I asked the wrong question...

Comment: I just found out that Qt Creator has its separate "Environment" with a set of environment variables that did not get updated with the PATH I changed. So I edited the PATH from the Environment of Qt